# constraining a route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a controller named results_controller. It uses

```
resources :results
```

in the router.

One problem is that I don't want people to be able to see the results page by typing in the following

```
www.example.com/results
```

Is there a way to put a redirect on that www.example.com/results  without interfering with any of the other resources :results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to not generate that specific route:

```
resources :results, :except => :index
// or you can use
resources :results, :only => [:show, :destroy]
```

Here's a good intro to rails routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I don't think that works.  I already tried your first suggestion, it did a redirect on www.example.com/results/index ; however, if I did www.example.com/results  there was no redirect and they saw the results